# How to develop a JAX-RS web service as a jar

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-boot, cxf

I am looking out a sample examples where i can develop as Rest based web services and bundled them as a **jar** not as **war/ear** etc.

These Jars are deployed in server containers(JBoss) and consumed.
Also, if i can develop using Spring with Rest Based seems to have a nice feature.

I am not getting any examples/approach to start off with. I looked into Apache CXF,Axis 2. All these are bundled as war files. But i need it as a jar file

Comment: You cannot deploy a jar file, so that isn't possible. Either you create a standalone jar file which contains the container (tomcat, jetty etc.) or create a war and deploy it to a container.

Comment: Spring Boot allow you create executable JAR file, Spring Framework also help you create RESTful web services. FYI: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html